Heat transfer with 100 percent efficiency?
The heat spontaneously flows from a hot object to a cold object.
If there is a hot object at temperature $T_1$ and a cold object at lower temperature $T_2$ and these objects are thermally connected. If the hot object releases 100 J of heat, will the cold object receive the full 100 percent of the heat?
This doubt arose because 100 percent of heat cannot be converted to work but can 100 percent efficient heat transfer occur or some heat would be lost to work even in ideal conditions?

Although Efficiency larger than one? is an interesting related discussion that merits a link, the current question, which is predicated on spontaneous heating down a temperature gradient, is arguably not a duplicate of that question, which is predicated on a heat pump operating up a temperature gradient.

If you have a completely isolated system such that the total energy $U=U_1+U_2$ is constant, then yes, any energy lost by one system must be gained by the other in order for energy to be conserved. I don't think we would usually call this "efficiency" though, since that term is usually associated with what we can get out of this interaction. Either way, it's certainly not the same type of efficiency as what we mean when talking about heat engines.

In the absence of work, and assuming there is no exchange of heat with other objects, conservation of energy dictates that the energy transferred out of the hotter object will equal the energy transferred into colder object.
Hope this helps.


This doubt arose because 100 percent of heat cannot be converted to work but can 100 percent efficient heat transfer occur or some heat would be lost to work even in ideal conditions?

The first constraint arises because (1) heat entropy is entropy transfer, (2) work transfers no entropy, and (3) entropy can't be destroyed, per the Second Law. Thus, in cyclic operation, one cannot input only heat and output only work and return to the same initial condition, as this would require entropy destruction. (One can, however, input only heat and output only work in noncyclic operation; here, the input entropy is stored in the object, through expansion, say.)
It is possible to heat an object and have its internal energy increase be

less than (if it expands),

more than (if it contracts; note that some materials have a negative thermal expansion coefficient), or

the same as (if its volume is fixed)


the heat transferred. (Here, I'm considering only heating and expansion work, not, for instance, chemical reactions.)
Thus, if you define "efficiency" as the internal energy increase per unit heat transferred, you could get a value other than 100%. You'd have to state this definition clearly, because it's somewhat unusual.
If you define "efficiency" in the standard way, as cyclic work collected per unit heat transferred, than the efficiency is always <100% because of the constraint described above.
